# Why do I get "Field elements" error in my array initialization?

Tags: python, numpy

I try to do this

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8])
```

and I get this:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-12-ac428719fc97> in <module>
      1 import numpy as np
----> 2 a = np.array([1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8])

TypeError: Field elements must be 2- or 3-tuples, got '5'
```

Comment: The correct way to create a 2d numpy array is: a = np.array([[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8]])

Comment: You're giving `np.array()` two parameters, which causes it to interpret the second list as a definition of fields, but that is done with 2- or 3-tuples, your list starts with a `5`, hence the error. Add the brackets as @NorbertTiborcz suggest, to defined a 2d array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that all the data needs to go into the first argument, and what you want to be the second row is now being read as the specification of the data type (because that's what the second argument of the array constructor is for).

If the array you are trying to create is:

[[1 2 3 4]
[5 6 7 8]]

then your code should be:

a = np.array([[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8]])

Comment: If you're not sure of an answer, try the solution yourself and verify, then post a clear answer, preferably with an example. Just reposting comments as an answer doesn't really help.

Comment: Thanks! I also didn't repost your comment, we both posted 3 minutes ago.